# List View vs react-native-collapsible

Tags: react-native

I have an app that is going to be rendering a long list. I want to make each section collapsible. I want to ask the experts here if i should use 'react-native-collapsible' to render this long list or if i should use list view rather. I don"t know how to make a collapsible list View so if anybody here can help. That would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

[ListView](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/listview.html) is actually deprecated, you should probably use a [FlatList](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html), passing an the array you use to populate each 'collapsible section' to the data prop and defining how the collapsibles will be and behave on the renderItem prop.